# handling onchange event on visural richtexteditor in wicket

Tags: wicket

for some reason I am not able to handle onchange event for the visural richetexteditor component in wicket, I am doing the same on a textarea but the same doesnt work for the rte, someone please help.

registerInstitutionPanel.getrteInstitutionForm().getRte()
                .add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

```
                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    message = registerInstitutionPanel.getInstDescription();
                    dynamicDisplay.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                    target.addComponent(dynamicDisplay);
                }
            });
```

am using message as a string to make a label dynamic, when I enter data into my richtexteditor I should see it in a label (a aspan) contained in a div (dynamicDisplay) is a webmarkupcontainer that contains the span for my display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

author of visural-wicket here - unfortunately this feature is not supported on the RTE component in the current version of the library. Most rich text editor components hide the underlying textarea and substitute it with a new component (the rich text editor) and the content is only synced with the placeholder component on form submission.

I can only suggest that you look into integrating your own Javascript editor instead. The library I used is http://nicedit.com/

Given visural-wicket is licensed under the Apache 2.0 licence, you are welcome to use it as a starting point, and by all means contribute back if you add useful features such as this one.

Comment: thanks Richard, let me try that, I think that will help me understand the rte component even more